# GLMM model selection: does the same model need to be applied for all data?

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models

This is more of a statistical problem than to do with code, therefore apologies if it's in the wrong place. I have a dataset where I'm comparing microbial respiration on the leaf litter of four different plant species over time. So far, I have built a model:

```
species1 <- lmer(respiration ~ treatment + (1+time|litterbag_ID))
```

where respiration is the response variable and there are two levels to the dependent variable (treatment). I have also included the random effect to account for repeated measures made over six time points.

Each of the four species has a model like this, however the respiration data is distributed slightly different for each species. My question is, can I apply different models to different species? For example, would I be correct in using the above model for species 1, whilst using the below GLMM for another species, if I find that it improves model fit using qqplots and AIC values?

```
species2 <- glmer(respiration ~ treatment + (1+time|litterbag_ID), family = (gaussian(link = "log"))
```

Comment: This sounds like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/can-aic-compare-across-different-types-of-model

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still not 100% sure, do you think I should be consistently applying the same transformation for all species if using it for one?